# How to map the target url on remote server while proxying in angular?

Tags: angular, frontend, http-proxy

I am working on angular 10 and need to access a resource which is located on a remote server. While sending the request using httpClient and httpParams, the following error has been consoled.

```
        Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows 
    reading the remote resource at https://xxxxxx.com/dev/profiles/?sector=a&weekend_prod=Yes.
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

I have researched and tried to setup a proxy in a json file -> **proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/dev/profiles/*": {
      "target": "https://xxxxxx.com",
      "secure": true,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

Also, I've configured it in angular ->
**angular.json**

```
 "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
```

However, I'm still getting the same error. Could you help me on solving this issue? Is the proxy configuration correct for the remote url with the query params?

Is the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header with the 'client url' or '*' must be setup on the backend response?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of remote server do you use? Do you have access to it?
It seems like the cors header still needs to be configured on your web server.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **Response** header, which needs to be set by your remote server. For testing purposes you could install a browser extension, which sets the header.

Comment: @code-gorilla  I do not have any access to the server (It's a test task, I just have the swagger documentation with the api endpoints). So, access control headers must be configured in the response?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm could you please recommend any extensions? and What's the use of proxying, if we can't access a certain resource?

Comment: In Chrome I have the extension `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` installed. Proxing in Angular can serve different purposes. Example 1: You have a http resource and a https app. Mixed content policy will not allow you to connect to the resource. You can proxy the http resource to get rid of the mixed content error. Example 2: You don't want the user to be able to see your backend url in the console. With proxy the console entry shows your apps domain.

Comment: Example 3: You have a backend with versioning (/api/v1, /api/v2) and in your http service you don't want to take care of which endpoint uses which version. You then can just say /api and in the proxy you rewrite the url to the actual version

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the information. Have a nice day!